# Is that possible to have a for loop in compile time with runtime or even compile time limit condition in c++11?

Tags: c++11, templates, for-loop, metaprogramming, compile-time

I would like to know if it is possible to have a for loop in compile time with runtime or even compile time limit condition in c++11?
I start with a silly try to find out what I need.

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    templated_func<i>();
  }
```

consider I have a class with a private member variable n, and I want to call a template function with a different number that iterates from 0 to n (for the case of runtime limit condition)
I've had studies on the "Template Metaprogramming" and "Constexpr If" (c++17) but I have not gotten any results, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know if it is possible to have a for loop in compile time with runtime or even compile time limit condition in c++11

I don't know a reasonable way to have such loop with a runtime condition.

With a compile time condition... If you can use at least C++14, you can use a solution based on `std::integer_sequence`/`std::make_integer_sequence` (see Caleth answer) or maybe `std::index_sequence`/`std::make_index_sequence` (just a little more synthetic).

If you're limited with C++11, you can create a surrogate for `std::index_sequence`/`std::make_index_sequence` or you can create a recursive template struct with static function (unfortunately you can partially specialize a template function but you can partially specialize classes and structs).

I mean... something as follows

```
template <std::size_t I, std::size_t Top>
struct for_loop
 {
   static void func ()
    {
      templated_func<I>();
      for_loop<I+1u, Top>::func();
    }
 };

template <std::size_t I>
struct for_loop<I, I>
 { static void func () { } };
```

that you can call

```
constexpr auto n = 10u;

for_loop<0, n>::func();
```

if you want to call `templated_func()` with values from zero to `n-1u`.

Unfortunately this solution is recursive so you can have troubles with compilers recursion limits. That is... works only if `n` isn't high.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a for loop, but you can call N lots of `templated_func`

```
namespace detail {
    template <template<uint32_t> class F, uint32_t... Is>
    void static_for_impl(std::integer_sequence<uint32_t, Is...>)
    {
        F<Is>{}()...;
    }
}

template <template<uint32_t> class F, uint32_t N>
void static_for()
{
    detail::static_for_impl<F>(std::make_integer_sequence<uint32_t, N>{}); 
}

template <uint32_t I>
struct templated_caller
{
    void operator()() { templated_func<I>(); }
}

int main()
{
    static_for<templated_caller, 10>();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this is more general than what you asked for. You can simplify it to just

```
template <uint32_t... Is>
void call_templated_func(std::integer_sequence<uint32_t, Is...>)
{
    templated_func<Is>()...;
}

int main()
{
    call_templated_func(std::make_integer_sequence<uint32_t, N>{});
    return 0;
}
```

but that's lengthy to repeat multiple times, and you can't pass a *function template* as a template parameter.

Comment: Thank you @Caleth, I'm sure this solution works on c++14|17, but unfortunately, I'm limited to c++11.

Comment: You can backport `std::integer_sequence` to C++11, but it's a bit of a faff. You can also adapt it to `call_templated_func<0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9>()`, removing the `std::integer_sequence` parameter by specifying exactly the list

Comment: This does not work for me. I get compiler error
`expected ';' before token '...'`

Answer (score 1):

As you said you only had C++11 then you will not have std::make_index_sequence and will have to provide it. Also, the fold expression in Caleth's answer is not available until C++17.

Providing your own implementation of index_sequence and a fold expression in c++11 can be done in the following way,

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t... Is>
struct index_sequence{};

namespace detail {
    template <size_t I,size_t...Is>
    struct make_index_sequence_impl : make_index_sequence_impl<I-1,I-1,Is...> {};

    template <size_t...Is>
    struct make_index_sequence_impl<0,Is...>
    {
        using type = index_sequence<Is...>;
    };
}

template<size_t N>
using make_index_sequence = typename detail::make_index_sequence_impl<N>::type;


template<size_t I>
void templated_func()
{
    std::cout << "templated_func" << I << std::endl;
}

template <size_t... Is>
void call_templated_func(index_sequence< Is...>)
{
    using do_ = int[];
    do_ {0,(templated_func<Is>(),0)...,0};
}

int main()
{
    call_templated_func(make_index_sequence< 10>());
    return 0;
}
```

This is essentially the same as the answer by @Caleth , but with the missing bits provided and will compile on c++11.

[demo](https://ideone.com/7QaJ47)

[demo](https://repl.it/repls/RevolvingUpsetDisplaymanager) on c++11 compiler

Comment: Your backport of `make_index_sequence` includes `N` in the sequence, whereas the standard excludes `N`. It should have `make_index_sequence_impl<I-1,I-1,Is...>` for the inductive case and `index_sequence<Is...>` for the base case.

Comment: `detail::make_index_sequence<N-1>::type` does infinite recursion for 0.

Comment: Ohh right, yes, then your solution is the way to go for sure.